# passing by reference in Java doubts

Tags: java

So I was reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) and response no. 2. In that example, after calling that method, does the Dog value at address 42, name's changes to Max?

```
Dog myDog;

Dog myDog = new Dog("Rover");
foo(myDog);

public void foo(Dog someDog) {
    someDog.setName("Max");     // AAA
    someDog = new Dog("Fifi");  // BBB
    someDog.setName("Rowlf");   // CCC
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java is pass by value - *always*, both for primitives and objects.

In the case of objects, the thing that's passed is the reference to the object that lives out on the heap.  A method cannot change what that reference points to when it's passed in.

If that reference points to an object that has mutable data, the method can alter its state.

From "The Java Programming Language Second Edition", by Ken Arnold and James Gosling (ISBN 0-201-31006-6 ) (probably from page 40--don't have the book handy right now):

> Some people will say incorrectly that objects in Java are "pass by
>   reference." The term pass by reference properly means that when an
>   argument is passed to a function, the invoked function gets a
>   reference to the original value, not a copy of its value. If the
>   function modifies its parameter, the value in the calling code will be
>   changed because the argument and parameter use the same slot in
>   memory. [...] There is exactly one ParameterPassing mode in Java--pass
>   by value--and that helps keep things simple.

So let's look at your example (with some improvements):

```
public class Dog {

    private String name;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Dog myDog = new Dog("Rover");
        System.out.println("before foo: " + myDog);
        foo(myDog);
        System.out.println("after  foo: " + myDog);
    }

    public static void foo(Dog someDog) {
        someDog.setName("Max");     // AAA
        someDog = new Dog("Fifi");  // BBB
        someDog.setName("Rowlf");   // CCC
    }

    public Dog(String n) { this.name = n; }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }

    public void setName(String n) { this.name = n; }

    public String toString() { return this.name; }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
before foo: Rover
after  foo: Max

Tool completed successfully
```

You can't change what the reference that's passed to `foo` points to, so setting it to the reference with the name "Fifi" at line BBB, and subsequently changing the name of that object at line CCC, does nothing.  That instance is eligible for garbage collection when `foo` exits.

The incoming reference that points to "Rover" has a mutable data member: its name.  Changing its value at line AAA is reflected in the reference that was passed in; hence the different output.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the topic that is confusing for most novice developers in Java. duffymo had already provided a detailed answer (I'm not going to repeat that) but I could give you some articles for reference that I hope would clear the doubt from your mind.

Jon Skeet's [article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html) about parameter passing in Java
[Pass-by-Value Please](http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp) 
[Does Java pass by reference or pass by value?](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html)

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

> that Dog (the one at address 42) is asked to change his name to Max

Yes

Answer (score 0):

> Does the Dog value at address 42, **name's** changes to Max?

Yes. The `name` changes

```
Dog myDog = new Dog("Rover");
foo(myDog);

public void foo(Dog someDog) {
    someDog.setName("Max");     // AAA
    someDog = new Dog("Fifi");  // BBB
    someDog.setName("Rowlf");   // CCC
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`myDog` and `someDog` share the same object and contain the same address value at the beginning. That is, both variables tell the JVM how to get to the Object Dog in memory (heap). So if you change something by invoking the `setName` method on `someDog`, `myDog` 'will feel' the effects!

After `someDog = new Dog("Fifi")` a new Object Dog is created (Fifi) and the `someDog` variable contains a new value/address for Fifi. That is, the value of `someDog` changes and will tell the JVM how to get to Fifi from now on. At this point, every change on `someDog` won't affect `myDog` anymore.

Check my answer (the one with the picture) on that post and note that I didn't use the word "pointer" and not even the word "reference" this time! ;)